# Reducing the gap between a bullet and text in a list item

Tags: css, html-lists

How can I reduce default gap between bullet and text in an `<li>`?

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

I want to reduce gap between the bullet and "I".

Comment: please also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332873/how-is-it-possible-to-modify-the-gap-between-a-bullet-and-its-list-text/65875936

Answer (score 33):

I'm not sure whether this is the best way to do it, but you could specify a negative [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-indent):

```
li {
    text-indent: -4px;
}
```

...where your HTML code looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

(Tested in Safari 4.0.4 and Firefox 3.0.11.)

Comment: it brings li outside the div in firefox

Comment: i got it i'm using list-style-position:inside; on <ul> also and ur solution not working with it but works without it. and why i'm using list-style-position:inside; on <ul> bcoz li bullets was going outside the div

Comment: the problem with negative text-indent (on Chrome anyway) is multi-line content doesn't work--only the first line is moved left, but subsequent lines are at the default spacing.

Comment: This doesn't change the space between the bullet and the text.  It only moves the li, including the bullet and the text.  The question was "how to reduce the space between the bullet and the text.

Answer (score 30):

You could achieve this by setting the `list-style-type` to `none`, and setting the `background-image` of a list element to a generic bullet, like so:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    background-image: url(bullet.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 50%;
    padding-left: 7px;
}
```

The outcome would look a little something like this:

[image]

With this approach, you aren't adding unnecessary `span` (or other) elements to your lists, which is arguably more practical (for later extendibility and other semantic reasons).

Comment: Ah, yes, I was thinking of that, too.  I do like keeping unnecessary markup and also allowing for something other than plain bullets.  Up vote.

Answer (score 24):

You could try the following. But it requires you to put a `<span>` element inside the `<li>` elements

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
ul.a li span{
position:relative;
left:-0.5em;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<ul class="a">
  <li><span>Coffee</span></li>
  <li><span>Tea</span></li>
  <li><span>Coca Cola</span></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 this worked well for me and is far better than the bullet technique imho

Comment: This is what i need to do with minimum practice- wonderful man you are strong man :)

Answer (score 22):

I've tried these and other solutions offered, which don't actually work, but I seem to have found a way to do this, and that is to remove the bullet and use the :before pseudo-element to put a Unicode bullet in its place. Then you can adjust the the space between the list item and bullet. You have to use Unicode to insert an entity into the content property of :before or :after - HTML entities don't work.

There's some sizing and positioning code needed too, because the Unicode bullet by default displays the size of a pinhead. So the bullet has to be enlarged and absolutely positioned to get it into place. Note the use of ems for the bullet's sizing and positioning so that the bullet's relationship to the list item stays constant when your change the font size of the list item. The comments in the code explain how it all works. If you want to use a different entity, you can find a list of the Unicode entities here:

http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/

Use a value from the far right column (octal) from the table on this page - you just need the \ and number. You should be able to trash everying except the content property from the :before rule when using the other entities as they seem to display at a useable size. Email me: charles at stylinwithcss dot com with any thoughts/comments. I tested it Firefox, Chrome and Safari and it works nicely.

```
    body {
      font-family:"Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
      }
    li  {
      font-size:14px;        /* set font size of list item and bullet here */
      list-style-type:none; /* removes default bullet */
      position:relative;      /* positioning context for bullet */
      }
      li:before  {
        content:"\2219";    /* escaped unicode character */
        font-size:2.5em;    /* the default unicode bullet size is very small */
        line-height:0;        /* kills huge line height on resized bullet */
        position:absolute;  /* position bullet relative to list item */
        top:.23em;           /* vertical align bullet position relative to list item */
        left:-.5em;            /* position the bullet L- R relative to list item */
       }
```

Comment: Huzzah! (Weird, I don't think I've ever said that before. Subconscious Simpsons influence coming through.)

Comment: Very nice! One tip for others reading this: if you want to use a disc (content: "\2022"), if you remove the line-height and top properties from this solution, it seems to work better. Also, if you want to use margin-left on the parent ul element to bump your list items inwards, remember to set it to be equal to the value of the li's "left" multiplied by its "font-size" (and positive, of course).

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen on the site so far; it avoids the shortcomings and inconsistencies of using spans within the list items with negative margin that are subject to each browser's native spacing; and it avoids having to maintain and load an image despite the control it gives you.

Comment: As others mentioned, this is--by far--the best solution to be found for this issue.  It is a requirement for my current project to scale in a very unconventional way, with all elements growing or shrinking maintaining their ratios as the browser is resized.  The stock UL/LI is simply incompatible with this requirement.  Suggestions to text-indent do not help, and images/spans feel a bit heavy.  But *this* solution is absolutely perfect.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If in every li you have only one row of text you can put text indent on li.
Like this :

```
ul {
  list-style: disc;
}
ul li {
   text-indent: 5px;
}
```

or

```
ul {
 list-style: disc;
}
ul li {
   text-indent: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You might try using:

```
li {list-style-position: inside; }
```

But I can't remember if that adjusts the *space*, or changes where the space *occurs*.

---

**Edited**

The above doesn't seem to make any substantial difference. There doesn't seem to be any way to *decrease* the space between the `list-style-type` marker and the text, though it can be *increased* using `margin-left` or `text-indent`.

Sorry I can't be of more use.

---

**Edited**

Just out of curiosity, how about 'faking' the bullet with a background image?

```
ul {list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {background: #fff url(path/to/bullet-image.png) 0 50% no-repeat;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0 0 0 10px; /* change 10px to whatever you feel best suits you */
}
```

It might allow for more fine-tuning.

Comment: @jitendra, see the edits; though I'm not sure if they'll make a huge difference.

Comment: Thanks for the `list-style-position: inside;` suggestion - really helpful. I had a centered `ol` within a `div` (nested in another `div`) where the text was centered fine, but for some reason the numbering was casted far-off to the left. Now the `ol` numbering is placed next to the list text as needed.

Answer (score 4):

This is one way.

```
    li span {
        margin-left: -11px;
    }

<ul>
    <li><span>1</span></li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: consecutive lines are indented as opposite to first in this approach

Answer (score 3):

Reduce `text-indent` to a negative number to decrease the space between the list item's bullet and its text.

```
li {
  text-indent: -4px;
}
```

You can also use `margin-left` to adjust any space between the list-item's bullet and the edge of its surrounding element.

```
li {
  margin-left: 24px;
}
```

Both `text-indent` and `padding-left` can *add* space between the bullet and text, but only `text-indent` can reduce space to negative.

<del>li { padding-left: -4px; } /* Doesn't work. */</del>

Comment: Great solution, and I love how it doesn't involve modifying the DOM, but this doesn't affect anything but the first row if the text wraps.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do this inline, and combined a few of the above to make it work right for me. I'm working inside a div and wanted to use an image:

The padding under the UL told the bullet where to start from the left margin of the div it's in. I use em for better accessibility/flexibility, but you could use px too. If it doesn't seem to move much with px, use a much larger px value (for me, just moving it in a cm was 60px!).

The text-indent tells the bullet how close to get to the text it's next to.

Hope it works for you! :)

Comment: +1 @libellus, thanks for the tip regarding `text-indent`.  Also using gpmcadam's solution and adding the text-indent worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have `<a>` inside the `<li>`s.

To the `<ul>` elements, apply the following CSS:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

To the `<a>` elements, apply the following CSS:

```
a:before {
    content: "";
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This creates pseudo elements for the bullets. They can be styled just like any other elements.

I've implemented it here: http://www.cssdesk.com/R2AvX

Comment: Clean and elegant. Unlike the other solutions, this works on my laptop as well as my mobile Chrome browser. I modified it slightly: `a:before {
   content: "";
   height: .4em;
   width: .4em;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: #000;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 .4em 0 0;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }`

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it.

Multi-line works perfectly if you do it this way. Bullet will automatically size with text. Indent is straight-forward: it's just the `padding-left` on the `li`. Minimal CSS required.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul > li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 12px;
}
ul > li:before {
  content: "•";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, explicabo iste numquam dolorem harum natus! Voluptate magni expedita, eaque voluptates, aliquam maiores vel quia repellat a ipsum possimus eveniet, blanditiis.</li>
    <li>Repudiandae repellendus laboriosam, odio vero debitis non quisquam provident deserunt, ratione facilis suscipit delectus sunt aliquid, in maxime autem optio, exercitationem iusto fugiat itaque omnis assumenda est a praesentium? Natus?</li>
    <li>Voluptatem, distinctio, eius, soluta, atque laboriosam tempora magnam sequi saepe architecto accusamus hic facilis! Tenetur, necessitatibus. Ut ipsam, officia omnis obcaecati vero consectetur vel similique nam consequatur quidem at doloremque.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here You Go with Fiddle:

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/a46fejho/)

> **HTML:**

```
<ol>
        <li>List 1          
            <ol>
                <li>Sub-Chapter</li>
                <li>Sub-Chapter</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>List 2
            <ol>
                <li>Sub-Chapter</li>
                <li>Sub-Chapter</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>List 3</li>
</ol>
```

> **CSS:**

```
ol {counter-reset:item;}
ol li {display:block;}
li:before {content:counters(item, ".");counter-increment:item;left:-7px;position:relative;font-weight:bold;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li:before {
    content: "";
    margin-left: "your negative value";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the standard bullets (`disc`, `circle`, `square`) in an unordered list appear to be an internal implementation of the browser, and if you compare the same list in different browsers, you'll notice that the size and spacing varies considerably. (The [specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-counter-styles-3/#simple-symbolic) are somewhat vague here.) If you want any kind of consistency, you need to define your own bullet and spacing.

Most older solutions do this by setting the `list-style-type` to `none`, then recreating the bullet in some non-standard way. These days, the solution is much simpler—just give `list-style-type` a string value which includes a bullet and a space. Unicode offers us a wide range of [whitespace characters](https://unicodeplus.com/category/Zs) to choose from. If you want to reduce the gap, choose a thinner space. Here's a list that uses a Thin Space (U+2009):

```css
ul {
   list-style-type: "•\002009";
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>item 1</li>
   <li>item 2</li>
   <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

While this solution may not give you that pixel-perfect placement that we've come to expect with `margin`, `padding` and `position` properties, it has two big advantages:

1. It reflects how lists work natively in the browser.
2. It's dead simple, using only one line of CSS!

If you want a little more control, you can tweak the appearance by declaring `font-size` and/or `font-family` on `li::marker`.

For more details about this solution, see my answer to the related question, [*CSS: Control space between bullet and `<li>`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73656713/2652785).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the look I wanted, I made a div containing a basic UL and several LIs. I couldn't easily adjust the indent between the bullet and text with any of the suggested ideas above (technically possible, but not simple.) I just left the UL and LI without any listing feature (`list-style-type: none`) then adding a `&bull;` to the beginning of each line. It did give me a bit of trouble at first, it only displayed the first bullet, so I added a bullet character to the end of the first line, refreshed, then removed it and they all popped up. Just manually add a bullet HTML entity if you don't want a huge indent, add space HTML entities if you want more space :o I know it isn't the best method, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
ul.list-group li {
     padding-left: 13px;
     position: relative;
}

ul.list-group li:before {
     left: 0 !important;
     position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's yet another way.

1. Add two divs to each li, one for the bullet, one for the text.
2. Put a bullet character `•` (or whatever you like, Unicode has plenty) in the bullet div. Put the text in the text div.
3. Set each li to `display:flex`.

Pros:

- No extra bullet image to add.
- No negative margins or anything, won't go outside of parent.
- Works on any browser that supports flexbox.
- Proper indentation of multiline items.
- Use of bullet character means bullet will always be properly vertically aligned with text, no tweaks necessary.

Cons:

- Requires extra elements.

Also, if you don't want to hand code all the extra divs, you can just make a normal list and then run this function to transform it, passing your `ul` as the parameter:

```
function fixList (theList) {
  theList.find('li').each(function (_, li) {
    li = $(li);
    $('<div/>').html(li.html()).appendTo(li.empty());
    $('<div/>').text('•').prependTo(li);
  });
}
```

Example:

```css
li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li > div:first-child {
  margin-right: 0.75ex; /* set to desired spacing */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div>•</div><div>First list item.</div>
  <li><div>•</div><div>Second list item.<br>It's on two lines.</div>
  <li><div>•</div><div>Third <i>list</i> item.</div>
</ul>
```

Here's an example using the function:

```js
fixList($('ul'));

function fixList (theList) {
  $('li', theList).each(function (_, li) {
    li = $(li);
    $('<div/>').html(li.html()).appendTo(li.empty());
    $('<div/>').text('•').prependTo(li);
  });
}
```

```css
li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li > div:first-child {
  margin-right: 0.75ex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>First list item.
  <li>Second list item.<br>It's on two lines.
  <li>Third <i>list</i> item.
</ul>
```

Comment: This is over-engineering the solution. It can be done with a simple :before style on the ul li