# How is it possible to modify the gap between a bullet and its list text?

Tags: css

I wantto reduce the gap between a bullet and its text in html ..

FOr instance I have

- This is the text

How is it possible to increase or decrease the gap between the bullet and The text using css?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Control space between bullet and <li>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've been able to achieve this [*decreasing the native browser rendered spacing of the li*] is by adding additional markup to your `li` and setting a negative margin.

As an example:

**Markup:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>This is the text</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li span { margin-left: -10px; }
```

This could add quite a bit of extra unnecessary markup for such a small requirement. You'd be better of using a background image on your `li` element which offers better position control without all the extra markup.

Answer (score 6):

Use text-indent with a negative value, like so:

```
li {text-indent:-8px}
```

Comment: This works great, but unfortunately if the text is more than 1 line long, it only works for the first line.

Comment: in my experience, that also moves the bullet so you do not achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it bigger by setting the padding on the `<li>`  element:

```
<ul >
    <li style="padding-left:20px;">test</li>
    <li>test 2 </li>
</ul>
```

i haven't been able to figure out how to make it smaller, negative values don't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this.

If your list-style is `inside` then you could remove the bullet and create your own ... e.g. (in scss!)

```css
li {
    list-style: none;
    &:before {
        content: '- ';
    }
}
```

And if you list style is `outside` then you could do something like this:

```css
li { 
    padding-left: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    &:before {
        content: '* '; /* use any character you fancy~! */
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: -10px;
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you do not end up with more complex HTML and that a  /

combination works out of the box.