# How to get rid of the padding between the disc and the li element?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've set the padding of the li element to 0 but there is still about 10 pixels worth of padding. How do I shorten the amount of padding provided?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441059/how-to-reduce-default-gap-between-bullet-and-text-in-li

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gqff8/

Comment: setting text-indent: -5px; as suggested in the duplicate SO question did the trick.

Comment: Use -.5em, so it scales correctly with the font-size of the li http://jsfiddle.net/gqff8/1/

Comment: There is no padding at all, as you can see inspecting the element.

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to be boring :) But in my opinion negative declaration `text-intend:-5px;` a kind of wrong trick. I know it does trick the browser default styles. But basically it just moves the text outside of the parent element, making something like a hanging intend. 
I've tried to find those browser inherited styles, but there are none of them that would create such padding around bullets/discs.

I did some research and found out that CSS3 has special pseudo-element [::marker](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#marker-pseudoelement) to address this issue. The idea is great, but unfortunately it is still not implemented in any browser :(

Mozilla has own temporary trick to better style bullets `:-moz-list-bullet` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:-moz-list-bullet
No other vendors that either support or have implemented such hack

CSS3 also has new value for list-style-position: [hanging](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#hanging), that may help. But it's still not well defined.

Another solution is to use pseudo-element `::before` (no support in IE7)

```
li:before { 
 content:"•";  
 margin-right:1px;
}
```

After all seems there is no any interest or need to address this issue. Everybody happy with `text-intend`.
In fairness in the end of the day why the heck would you want to remove that space between bullet and text :)) I think that's the case they called - accidental implementation