# CSS padding to list items only applied in IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a list of items I'm putting together to scroll across the screen in a ticker.

I have all the CSS working across all browsers except for one element, padding.

You can see in this fiddle the padding left of 12px only works in IE, not in any other browser.

I've tried messing with just about everything I can think of to get it to work in Chrome/Firefox/Safari to no avail.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gmvmc/3/

```
<div class="exchange-rates">
Exchange rates $ 1 USD:
<a href="http://finance.yahoo.com/currency-converter/" target="_blank">
    <div id="scrollerWrapper">
        <ul id="scroller">
            <li id="USDJPY">TEST</li>
            <li id="USDAUD">TEST</li>
            <li id="USDEUR">TEST</li>
            <li id="USDGBP">TEST</li>
            <li id="USDCHF">TEST</li>
            <li id="USDCAD">TEST</li>
            <li id="USDSEK">TEST</li>
            <li id="USDNOK">TEST</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</a>
```

```
.exchange-rates
{
background:#eeeeff;
padding:10px 19px 10px 59px;
border:1px solid #222266;
color:#222266;
font-size:1.1em;
border-radius:9px;
margin:0 0 0 0;
}
#scrollerWrapper
{
height:25px;
overflow:hidden;
width:70%;
float:right;
}
#scroller
{
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position:relative;
color:#222266;
}
#scroller li
{
float:left;
padding:0 0 0 12px;
list-style-position:inside;
}
```

Comment: avoid using anchors to block level elements. use javascript/jquery for click event.

Comment: Did you try margin-left instead of padding-left?

Comment: it's working properly. check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Gmvmc/6/

Comment: Seems to work fine for me - if you inspect the element then you can see there is 12px padding on, just not enough for the bullet to be rendered without overlapping, increasing it to 18px seems to sort out the bullet problem

Comment: Margin-left has the same result. @Nitesh the padding is being applied across browsers but in vastly different fashions.  It's off by at least 10px in Chrome/Safari/Firefox vs. IE

Comment: @Tom I think you should take from this that IE's rendering is crap (as usual) which is why we have the use of [IE only stylesheets](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Comment: Works fine for me also.

Comment: @Pete: agreed but I don't want to use a different style sheet for just this one element that is off, seems like overkill.

Comment: if you don't want to add a whole stylesheet you could do [something like this](http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie10-css-hacks/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom, I'm guessing what your really trying to achieve here is some control over the space between the bullet and the text of the LI.  If so, your most consistent cross-browser solution would be something like this:

```
#scroller li
{
float:left;
padding:0 0 0 12px;
list-style-position:inside;
    list-style: none;
}
#scroller li:before
{
    content: "\2022";
    margin-right: 10px;/* space between bullet and text */
}
```

Strongly recommend using the ISO value for the bullet rather than just a bullet in quotes.
More here: [how to reduce default gap between bullet and text in <li>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441059/how-to-reduce-default-gap-between-bullet-and-text-in-li).