# align text of LIs with other elements

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists

Our graphic designer sent me the following image for how our page should look:

[image]

So the text of the `<li>` elements should be aligned with the logo at the top and the heading above the list. I can't seem to find a way to specify this relationship precisely. I ended up tweaking the `margin-left` style of `li` until they seemed about even with the heading in my browser, but that doesn't seem like it will be reliable across different devices and browsers. There's no direct relationship between `padding-left: 1em;` on the `#image-header` and `#instruction-header` DIVs that contain the first two elements, and `margin-left: 1.3em` on `#instructions li`.

Is there a way to style these so that the alignment is assured?

And if I line up the text, can I be sure that the numbers won't end up outside the page boundary?

```css
#image-header {
  background-color: #fcfb91;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.image-container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#instructions li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
}
#instruction-header {
  background-color: #336699;
  color: white;
  width: 20em;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-header">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="//dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/mp/acbl/bbo.png" alt="BBO Logo">
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="//dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/mp/acbl/invitetext.png" alt="Invite some friends">
  </div>
</div>
<div style='font-family: "Ariel", sans-serif'>
  <h3 id="instruction-header">How it works</h3>
  <ol id="instructions">
    <li>Every friend you invite who has not played an ACBL tournament on BBO is eligible for the promotion.</li>
    <li>Each of you will earn BB$5 when your friend creates a BBO username (if he's not already a BBO user) and registers a valid ACBL number. The bonus will be automatically deposited in each of your BBO accounts.
    </li>
    <li>There is no limit to the number of bonuses you can earn within the deadline of the promotion.</li>
    <li>Once you refer, each friend will receive an email from BBO.</li>
    <li>The deadline is Nov 1, 2015. Your friend must use that referral email to successfully create a BBO username and register his ACBL number by that date for both of you to earn the bonuses.
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: If the elements are not related then margin tweaking is probably the only option. Unless this is an absolute requirement (which seems unduly precise) it's probably something to push back on. Believe me, users wont know they're *supposed* to line up and won't notice.

Comment: Although...`list-style-position:inside` might be a place to start.

Comment: Couple of other links for you.- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441059/how-to-reduce-default-gap-between-bullet-and-text-in-li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove the left margin from #instructions li, and instead define the left-padding of #instructions ol. If you set it to 1em, it perfectly aligns with the logo

Edit: Here you go:

```css
#image-header {
  background-color: #fcfb91;
  padding-top: 5px;

}
.image-container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}    

#instructions, #image-header {
  padding-left: 1em;
}

#instructions li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#instruction-header {
  background-color: #336699;
  color: white;
  width: 20em;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-header">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="//dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/mp/acbl/bbo.png" alt="BBO Logo">
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="//dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/mp/acbl/invitetext.png" alt="Invite some friends">
  </div>
</div>
<div style='font-family: "Ariel", sans-serif'>
  <h3 id="instruction-header">How it works</h3>
  <ol id="instructions">
    <li>Every friend you invite who has not played an ACBL tournament on BBO is eligible for the promotion.</li>
    <li>Each of you will earn BB$5 when your friend creates a BBO username (if he's not already a BBO user) and registers a valid ACBL number. The bonus will be automatically deposited in each of your BBO accounts.
    </li>
    <li>There is no limit to the number of bonuses you can earn within the deadline of the promotion.</li>
    <li>Once you refer, each friend will receive an email from BBO.</li>
    <li>The deadline is Nov 1, 2015. Your friend must use that referral email to successfully create a BBO username and register his ACBL number by that date for both of you to earn the bonuses.
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: The application that uses this page is no longer in use, so I'm not going to try your suggestion. But if you make a stack snippet that shows that it works, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I edited it, turns out just styling #instructions did the trick